# Show that $F$ is not a one-to-one transformation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation

Given

$$F(x,y)=(x-y,y^2-x-2)=(u,v),$$

how to show that this transformation is not one-to-one? And at which points $F$ is locally one to one?

While I was drawing this transformation I found that the effect of $F$ on some horizontal lines ($y=-1$ and $y=-2$) are the same. Does this demonstrate that the transformation is not one-to-one?

Also, the effect of $F$ on vertical lines are one-to-one locally, I think.

Comment: Have you thought of the Inverse Function Theorem?

Comment: You can find infinitely many pair of distinct points $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ such that $f(a,b)=f(a',b')$!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F$ is not injective because $F(0,0)=F(1,1)$.

The inverse function theorem implies $F$ is locally invertible at a point $p$ if the Jacobian $J$ of $F$ at $p$ is invertible. Since
$$
\det J
=
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & -1 \\
-1 & 2\,y
\end{bmatrix}
=2\,y-1
$$
we see that this ensures that $F$ is locally invertible at every point $p=(x,y)$ where $y\neq 1/2$.

Can you determine if $F$ is locally invertible when $y=1/2$?

Comment: Yes!! F is not invertible when y=1/2 since the determinant is 0 right?

Comment: Not exactly. Just because $\det J\neq 0$ does not imply that $F$ is not locally invertible.

Comment: Are there any other conditions needed to show that F is not locally invertible?

Comment: Or maybe I can try to solve for the inverse function by plugging in y=1/2